# Search query combined with "duplicate:0" skips many posts

Tags: support, bug

I Have a custom filter setup for me, as `[c++] or [c++11] or [c++17] or [c++14] or [c++20] or [c++98] or [c++03]` to see most C++ related questions. It returns about 700,000 questions. However, there are many of them marked `[duplicate]`.

So naturally, my thought is to filter out all the questions marked duplicate. With some researches, I found `duplicate:0`, and combined it with my original filter, as `duplicate:0 and ([c++] or [c++11] or [c++17] or [c++14] or [c++20] or [c++98] or [c++03])`. Now it only returns about 7000 results., about 1% of the original.

Pretty shocked by the result at first. Then I've noticed if I sort them by newest question first, the first result goes to my search is a question from about 18 hours ago, whereas my original query would have multiple questions that are not duplicate from just couple minutes ago.

So I thought maybe there's some delay to the `duplicate:0` part. But then, even if I scroll the questions all the way to about 18 hours ago with my original filter, there are still around 15 question in between the 1st newest and 2nd newest questions with my second filter.

And if I use only `duplicate:0` without `([c++] or [c++11]...)`, it will once again show questions from just minutes or seconds ago.

#### Question:

Am I using the search query wrong, or if the query isn't working properly?

Comment: Eh, this is search being dumb. On-site search always has been complete and utter trash. If you remove `duplicate:0 and` from the second search, keep parentheses, you'll notice that it searches for the string literal `[c++]` and not the tag. Far from all questions tagged C++ have version tags. `duplicate:no and [c++] or [c++11] or [c++17] or [c++14] or [c++20] or [c++98] or [c++03]` works, although it makes no logical sense

Comment: you actually don't need an `and` at all for `duplicate:no`.

Comment: @Zoe Ah, I see. Would you mind to put that down as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thank you!

Comment: @Zoe Apparently, `and` is not required for any searches, `tag`s can be concatenated to each other without spaces, but they have to have a ` `(space) go before them if there's anything other than a tag before them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your search is actually that the on-site search bugs and assumes `[c++]` is a string literal rather than a tag. Your second search yielding 7000 results are for all posts tagged with one of the version-specific tags, that also contain "C++".

You can work around this by removing the parentheses around the or group, and while this logically doesn't make sense (because you'd end up with [c++] questions that aren't a dupe, or C++ questions tagged with version tags), it makes sense to the system because `duplicate:no` doesn't  require an `and` to be a part of the query. Certain conditions, including `duplicate:no` applies to the entirety of the search, and not just one tag or one search requirement.

So both `duplicate:no and [c++] or [c++11] or [c++17] or [c++14] or [c++20] or [c++98] or [c++03]` and `duplicate:no [c++] or [c++11] or [c++17] or [c++14] or [c++20] or [c++98] or [c++03]` (or with `duplicate:no` at the end rather than at the start, although that's pure preference) both work. In the first one though, `and` is silently discarded presumably because the query parser reads `(<blank> and <real condition>) or tag=c++11 ...`, which is just shortened to `<real condition> or tag=c++11 ...`. This is also one of the many reasons why on-site search is awful.

Also, note that your first result also includes answers. If you add `is:q` to the query, you only get questions. `is:q` (short for `is:questions`) is also used exactly like `duplicate:no`: add it to the start or end of the search, don't use `and`, and don't add parentheses, and it [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B11%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B17%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B14%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B20%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B98%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B03%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=1). Has no effect on the broken query of course, but it means you get a more accurate query. No idea if you need it of course, but it's always nice to know stuff.