# Filter questions with multiple tags using "OR" and excluding multiple tags doesn't work

Tags: support, bug, tags, filtering

There are [numerous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271236/how-to-search-for-questions-not-containing-a-certain-tag) topics already discussing how to exclude a tag or two in a filter, however all of them seems to work only if tags without `or` are used.
As soon as `or` added it ignores the `not` tags.

For example I want to create a filter to see questions with `[javascript]` OR `[html]` tags and exclude `[jquery]` and `[css]`
So my filter looks like this:
`[javascript] or [html] -[jquery] -[css]`
However it still shows questions with `[jquery]` or `[css]` tags.
If I remove the `or` it excludes `[jquery]` and `[css]`, however it only shows questions with both `[javascript]` AND `[html]`. In the search we can use parenthesis and it works fine like this:
`([javascript] or [html]) -[jquery] -[css]`, but we can't use parenthesis in the filter for some reason.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want `[javascript] or [html] and -[jquery] -[css]`, because [on-site search is trash with mixed `and` and `or`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402267/6296561) (and just in general - on-site search is awful the second you need text or filters exceeding tag combinations represented with basic and or or)

Comment: nope, still shows questions with [css] and [jquery] tags

Answer (score 2):

As I just discovered while investigating [a similar filtering question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419451), the answer you're looking for here is:

> [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) -[jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) -[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) -[jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) -[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)
>
> <sub>Filter text:
> javascript and not jquery and not css or html and not jquery and not css</sub>

Which spells out exactly what `([javascript] or [html]) -[jquery] -[css]` is designed to mean using the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property).

As for *why* this occurs, standard practice dictates that in boolean logic `AND` takes precedence over `OR`. This means that the query `[javascript] or [html] -[jquery] -[css]` gets interpreted by the filter logic as:

> ( [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) ) or
> ( [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) -[jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) -[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) )

This is the reason you can get questions in the original filter tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)– they satisfy the first `OR` clause!