# Custom questions filter with multiple AND, OR and NOT is broken

Tags: bug, filtering, custom-filter, tag-filters

I want to create a custom filter that matches my interests. But I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I only want to see questions that:

(java OR spring-boot OR spring-data) and NOT android and NOT android-studio NOT javascript.

My first thought was to use parentheses, so I first tried the following search term in the search: `( [java] or [spring-boot] or [spring-data] ) and -[android] and -[android-studio] and -[javascript]`

The search result seems to match my interest. Now I want to save it as a custom filter to access it more easily, but it seems that I can't use them in the "Tagged with The following tags:" section because the parentheses are removed when I copy them into that field. When saved as a filter

- it becomes: `[java] or [spring-boot] or [spring-data] and -[android] and -[android-studio] and -[javascript]`.
- displayed as `Tagged with java or spring-boot or spring-data and not android and not android-studio and not javascript`.

Without the parentheses, I get results that don't match my interest, such as questions with these tags:

- [java][android][opencv] ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123936/java-opencv-templatematching-assertion-failed-depth-cv-8u-depth-cv-3) (I don't want android)
- [javascript][spring-boot][gzipstream] ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124275/how-to-convert-and-download-binary-data-from-response-in-plain-java-script)) (I don't want javascript)

What's even stranger is that the filter is saved as shown above, BUT when I copy the URL I get right after selecting the custom filter into another browser, the query changes completely:

- URL directly after selecting the filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+spring-boot+or+spring-data+and+-android+and+-android-studio+and+-javascript?sort=Newest&uqlId=62888
- After copying this URL to another browser, it is immediately changed/rewritten to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+spring-boot+or+spring-data

Even more interesting is that both URLs get the same filtered questions:

[image: Saved filter URL vs. rewritten after copying to another browser]

I think this shows that the filtering is buggy and ignores the negated tags (`and -[android] and -[android-studio] and -[javascript]`), even though they can be saved and loaded as a custom filter. This would explain to me why I still see questions like the ones above (e.g. [java][android][opencv]).

Now I'm wondering...

- Why are the negated tags ignored and even removed when copied to another browser?
- Is it at all possible to create a custom filter like I specified?
- Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: Why not just bookmark the search page that works for you?

Comment: Then it shows both questions and answers with no option to limit it to questions only. I only want to see questions like in the "Questions" tab

Comment: Add `is:q`⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Thanks! `is:q` helps. But I want to use this filter on multiple devices, some are changing once in a while. It would be more convenient if it could be saved to my SO account as a custom filter

Comment: Is there a reason why the custom filters are so limited? I think this is a relatively simple filter, I could imagine much more complex filters used on a daily basis. Actually I would like to create a filter based on this filter, with more languages and frameworks/libraries (like C#, ASP.NET, ...) that exactly match my interests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've got a solution for you: [the Distributive Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property).

Since filters don't handle parenthesis, as you've already discovered, when you save a filter with this:

> [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot) or [spring-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data) and not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and not [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) and not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

It gets interpreted as this:

> ( [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) ) or
> ( [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot) ) or
> ( [spring-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data) and not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and not [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) and not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) )

But what we're really looking for is to get the "not" portion on all 3 base tags. To do this, we can just copy and paste the negated tags portion to the end of each base tag, to get:

> [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and not [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) and not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or
> [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot) and not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and not [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) and not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or
> [spring-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data) and not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and not [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) and not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

It's verbose, but it works!

> [image: Search with tags and parenthesis showing roughly 1,621,000 results returned]

> [image: Filter with negated tags distributed across the 3 desired tags, showing roughly the same amount of results returned]

<sub>(I'm really not sure how to explain the 44 question difference; my guess is search or caching quirks)</sub>

---

Filter text (for copying convenience):

> java and not android and not android-studio and not javascript or spring-boot and not android and not android-studio and not javascript or spring-data and not android and not android-studio and not javascript

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome! I thought about it for a second too, but immediately abandoned the idea and never considered it again because it seemed too ugly and cumbersome.... :D  I was really hoping there was a better way, or that I was missing something. But if it's the only way to use custom filters, I'll do it. Maybe I'll write a little script at some time to convert search queries in the disjunctive normal form to use them as custom filters.

Comment: I am trying this: `[javascript] and -[reactjs] or [jquery] and -[reactjs] or [html] and -[reactjs]` which is not at all the same as `javascript and not reactjs or jquery and not reactjs or html and not reactjs` - the result messages are also completely different. My original gives tons of newer questions too: `[javascript] or [jquery] or [html]`