# Filter Tags with logic groups (parentheses)

Tags: support, tags, search

I filter tags like this:

```
[tag1] [tag2] OR [tag3]
```

As far as I see, all of the results include [tag1]. But I want to also include questions that are tagged with [tag3] without [tag1].
So I tried:

```
([tag1] AND [tag2]) OR [tag3]
```

However, grouping with the parentheses is not supported.

Is there some way to do this or am I doing this wrongly?

I found a similar question for Filter Questions, but it didn't help me.

[Filter Questions that have one of multiple tags and don't have all of multiple tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337714/filter-questions-that-have-one-of-multiple-tags-and-dont-have-all-of-multiple-t/359942#359942)

Comment: [so]'s search tool is pretty rudimentary. It does not support such syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer thanks to this:

[Filter questions with multiple tags using "OR" and excluding multiple tags doesn't work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409015)

> As for why this occurs, standard practice dictates that in boolean
> logic AND takes precedence over OR.

so writing

```
[tag1] [tag2] OR [tag3]
```

does already what I wanted.